# cURL cert validation with curlopt_cainfo not working

Tags: tls, certificates, php

I want to validate my SSL certificate each time I run API calls. I've been following this guide:

http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/how-to-properly-secure-remote-api-calls-from-php-application

This is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($apiCredentials . $nvpStr));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Returnerar resultatet istället för att skriva ut det

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, curlopt_cainfo, (dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem'));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

The problem is that my SSL cert is not validated at all - it seems the file cacert.pem isn't even checked! I have changed name of the file, deleted it, and I've even tried editing it by removing all certificates in the cacert.pem file that are from my certificate issuer. The API call is still run no matter what!

What might the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple :-)

First of all I got some weird errors when I run your script:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant curlopt_cainfo - assumed 'curlopt_cainfo' in ...
PHP Warning:  curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in ...
```

So I replaced with `curlopt_cainfo` with `CURLOPT_CAINFO` - that seems to get rid of them.

I added the following after `curl_exec()` call:

```
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
```

When I missed the `cacert.pem` or the path was invalid it showed:

```
Curl error: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

After I tried to hack-in the certificate from the paypal site like this (do **NOT** do this on production environment):

```
openssl s_client -connect api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com:443 </dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > cacert.pem
```

It complained again

```
Curl error: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
```

After properly supplying a certificate bundle from mozilla:

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -O cacert.pem
```

It works just fine :-)

I don't think you have to supply the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option as curl comes bundled with the `cacert.pem` from mozilla and this should work out of the box with just `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` enabled.

Comment: Ah, at last someone who knows! I'm currently moving to a new server, and when it's done I'll try this out, thanks alot! Though, I don't understand this line: "wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -O cacert.pem". Can I do the same thing using PHP cURL as in my example above? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Marcus,

that is just to get a proper cacert.pem that contains world-wide trusted certification authorities (CA) - this particular one is an export from Mozilla.

I got it from here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

But as I said earlier - curl should have this bundled, so you should not need the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` line at all.

Feel free to ping me once you've migrated if you have troubles.